# Delete Email Names?

Tags: notepad++

```
https://adharia78@gmail.com:lat66pie@www.walmart.com/account/login
https://teresecharlene3@gmail.com:Reecewalker2431@controlboard.getcontrol.co/login
```

I need

```
adharia78@gmail.com:lat66pie
teresecharlene3@gmail.com:Reecewalker2431
```

I try `([@]*)@.*` replace with `$1` but not working

Comment: ^https://(.*)\@.* should work

Answer (score 1):

```
https?:\/\/([^@]+).*
```

**Try the above regex and replace it with** `$1`

Explanation ([from here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=https%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%28%5B%5E%40%5D%2B%29.*)):

```
    NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^@]+                    any character except: '@' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `https?://([^:]+:[^@]+).*`
- **Replace With:** `\1`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

The **Find What** RE searches for:

1. a literal `http` followed by an optional `s` (due to the `?`)
2. a literal `://`
3. then we capture :

   1. everything not a `:`  (`[^:]+`)
   2. the literal `:`
   3. everything not a `@` (`[^@]+`)

   into `\1` (by putting it into parenthesis)
4. and we consume everything up to end of line (`.*`)